# Django on_delete=models.CASCADE has no effect at SQL level

Tags: python, mysql, django, cascade, cascading-deletes

My `models.py` file contains:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Session(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

When i command `python manage.py makemigrations` and then command `python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_name> <migration_name>` i don't see anything that says "ON DELETE=CASCADE"

However, the migrations work without failure when i type `python manage.py migrate`.

Now, if i go to the mysql table (using SequelPro) and try to delete a row for a user who currently has a session entry,  i get the following error: "***One row was not removed. Reload the table to be sure that the contents have not changed in the meantime. Check the Console for possible errors inside the primary key(s) of this table!***".

Now, when i go to the session table and delete the sessions of this user and then try to delete the user's row from the user table, it deletes properly. This indicates `ON DELETE = CASCADE` is not actually working at the MySQL level.

How can i correct it?

Answer (score 31):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) (emphasis mine):

> ForeignKey.on_delete
>
> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django will
>   **emulate** the behavior of the SQL constraint specified by the on_delete
>   argument.

Django does not actually set an `ON DELETE` clause in the database. If you need one, you can add one manually using a [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunSQL) operation. Be sure to use the same index name, or keep the original index, or you might run into errors later on.

Comment: that is such a bummer :(

Comment: [Here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961) you can check out the **feature request**. Django maintainers are planning to implement this feature.

Comment: I feel so lucky to have found this answer!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "Be sure to use the same index name, or keep the original index"?